# Like and Where in the same MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, sql-like

I would like to use something like the following:

```
SELECT city FROM cities WHERE city LIKE %D% AND country_id = '12'
```

Comment: put single-quotes around the `%D%`; other than that your query looks good.  are you getting errors?  if so, please post them.

Comment: Generally I use ilike for case insensitivity.

Comment: @Tchalvak: ilike? What do you mean?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I swapped up postgresql and mysql, mysql matching is case insensitive to start with, my bad.

Comment: case sensitivity depends on collation in mysql. the default is a case-insensitive collation of latin1. but it's not the case that mysql matching is case insensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to quote the string

```
SELECT city FROM cities WHERE city LIKE '%D%' AND country_id = '12'
```

But remember that using a LIKE with a pattern starting with a "%" means the server will NOT use an index on 'city' column - it may not matter in your specific case but something to be aware of. [Here's the reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html) since your comment indicates you're not familiar with indexes.

Comment: What do you men it will not use an index on the city column? what problems could the have?

Comment: @Josh - I added the link to the documentation which explains that.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the show... But I had the same problem when using it as a "search" feature. Remember in PHP, you need to concatenate it or it might break... Like this

`$query="SELECT city FROM cities WHERE city LIKE '%".$searchterm."%' AND country_id = '12'"`

Maybe not relevant to you but if like me you looked around for ages to find out why the "search term" was not being put in in a recognisable format, this might help.